# Hide top bar in vue-form-wizard

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to hide the [vue-form-wizard](https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard) top bar that indicates what step someone is on.

Is there a simple prop to use? I can't seem to find one in the documentation.

[image]

```
<form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete" 
                  shape="square"
                  color="#3498db">
        <tab-content title="Personal details"
                     icon="ti-user">
          My first tab content
        </tab-content>
        <tab-content title="Additional Info"
                     icon="ti-settings">
          My second tab content
        </tab-content>
        <tab-content title="Last step"
                     icon="ti-check">
          Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple
        </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
```

```
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 methods: {
  onComplete: function(){
      alert('Yay. Done!');
   }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bt5dhqtf/98/

Comment: if there is not an option (I dont feel inclined to look) use CSS `.wizard-nav.wizard-nav-pills,.wizard-progress-with-circle{display:none}`

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone that works. Was mainly just wondering if theres a better way to do this that I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

```
.wizard-progress-with-circle {
  display: none;
}
.wizard-nav.wizard-nav-pills {
  display: none;
}
```

You should add this style to css file.